# What are the maintenance benefits of SABRE engine technology for SSTO launchers?

Tags: rockets, engines, sabre-engine

What are the maintenance benefits of the [SABRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SABRE_(rocket_engine)) engine over all the other engines being considered for the propulsion concepts for SSTO Reusable launchers?

Comment: What research have you done for yourself on this topic? What do you think are the key requirements for such an engine?

Comment: Olly, if you could specify what exactly you are looking for when you refer to "maintenance", maybe that would help us better understand how to answer your question.

Comment: For example how easy it is to maintain the SABRE engine compared to the other engines that are being considered

Comment: It may be a tad difficult to scope the maintenance effort for an engine that's never been built, let alone flown.